# "Failed to initialize display event receiver" after deep sleep

Tags: android

I have made an app which can fire an alarm. 
I use the **AlarmManager** to schedule the alarm. This works fine and the app receives the alarm every time in a BroadcastReceiver.

In the broadcast receiver I show a Notification like this:

```
    Intent reminder_intent = new Intent(ctxt, ReminderActivity.class);
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("event_id");
    String event_title = intent.getStringExtra("event_title");
    String event_description = intent.getStringExtra("event_body");
    reminder_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    reminder_intent.putExtra("reminder_title", event_title);
    reminder_intent.putExtra("reminder_millis", intent.getLongExtra("event_millis", 0));
    reminder_intent.putExtra("reminder_description", event_description);
    reminder_intent.putExtra("reminder_background", ctxt.getResources().getColor(intent.getIntExtra("event_color", 0xff000000)));
    reminder_intent.putExtra("reminder_event_id", id);
    reminder_intent.putExtra("reminder_notify_id", id);
    reminder_intent.putExtra("ringerMode", ringerMode);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, ALARM_ID, reminder_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification note = new Notification.Builder(ctxt)
            .setVibrate(vibraPattern)
            .setContentTitle(event_title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(intent.getLongExtra("event_millis", 0))
            .setSound(alarmSound, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
            .setTicker(event_description)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pi, false)
            .setContentIntent(launch_pi)
            .build();
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    manager.notify(id, ALARM_ID, note);
```

This starts the fullScreenIntent "pi", which run its onCreate-method. After that the app crashes with the error: "**Failed to initialize display event receiver**". BUT only when the device is in deep sleep mode. Maybe after a full night of inactivity. Else this works perfectly. 
I have been searching this problem for a long time and found others with the same problem, but no solution.
Refer this Link: [Link](http://boleware-techaswere1.blogspot.dk/2013/10/android-failed-to-initialize-display.html)

Comment: I have same error on a nexus 7 on 4.4.2. Only occurs after the app has been in deep sleep for several hours. Did you find more about the issue or any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I use uncaughtexception to catch the crash and then I relaunch the application with same intent action and extra data. Not a good solution...